# submit app to itune connect with different default language then english ( No application records were found.)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit in app with different default language then English in itunes connect but when I try to validate or submit the app via xcode I'm getting this error:

No application records were found.
Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

Any of you knows what can I be doing wrong? or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your default language - you have to actually create an app and a version in iTunes Connect before you can submit your binary. The latter should have a version number matching the one you put in the project settings.